# Facebook graph API: get the "subcomments" in a tree of a discussion

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to download a Facebook discussion using the graph API. The problem is: the discussion is located in a page, and in a tree-style manner, meaning that there are two types of comments: "main" comments, to the first message, and "subcomments" to the main comments themselves.

It seems that the graph result only shows the "main" comments and doesn't show the subcomments. Here's an example of a comment it returns:

```
{
  "id": "53526364352_1574091", 
  "can_remove": false, 
  "created_time": "2014-02-05T10:46:37+0000", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Main commenter", 
    "id": "5345353"
  }, 
  "like_count": 163, 
  "message": "I am a main comment", 
  "user_likes": false
},
```

There is no link or whatever to the subcomments of this main comment (and there are many).

Is there a way to get the subcomments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `10101140614002197_8831228` is an ID of a root comment, then you can check for subcomments/replies by requesting `COMMENT_ID/comments`.

For example:

- the root comment: http://graph.facebook.com/10101140614002197_8831228
- the subcomment: http://graph.facebook.com/10101140614002197_8831228/comments
- this root comment has no subcomments so the `data` list is empty: https://graph.facebook.com/10101140614002197_8831286/comments

Comment: Thanks! Why doesn't the graph explorer show that a main comment HAS this /comment section?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't, but it really should contain such info. At the moment we are forced to request every comment for subcomments, which generates a whole lot of unnecessary traffic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use field expansion (curly parenthesis in url) to get nested data

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{object-id}/comments?fields=id,message,comments{id,message,comments{id,message,comments}}
```

More info [here](https://www.sammyk.me/optimizing-request-queries-to-the-facebook-graph-api) in the section labeled `Nested requests (a.k.a. field expansion)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to traverse and flatten the tree, you can do this:

```py
def get_all_comments(post_or_comment_id):
    next_ids = [post_or_comment_id]
    results = []
    while next_ids:
        next_id = next_ids.pop()
        comments = get_comments_from_facebook(next_id)   # Facebook API call
        results += comments
        next_ids.extend(c["id"] for c in comments)
    return results
```

Make sure to add `parent` to the API call so you can replicate the tree.