# Get comment on owned page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-page

I owned a page on Facebook. My purpose is I want to collect all the comments, replies within my page which is made by user as well as the thread ID of the comment.

I have read the document of Facebook's Graph API and it describes:

```
Page owned Comments and Replies — For any comments or replies owned by (on) a Page, you must use a Page access token if you want User information to be included in the response
```

I am confused, I had the access token but the API endpoint looks like:

```
GET /v4.0/{comment-id} HTTP/1.1
```

Does that mean I have to specify a comment-id in order to get it? May you please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the correct endpoint: GET /v4.0/{post-id}/comments HTTP/1.1

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/)

Subcomments: GET /v4.0/{comment-id}/comments HTTP/1.1

([Facebook graph API: get the "subcomments" in a tree of a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280955/facebook-graph-api-get-the-subcomments-in-a-tree-of-a-discussion))

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your time to help me. According to your answer, does that mean I don't not need to post the page ID to get it post? Or Facebook can determine page ID by access token? Thanks.

Comment: if you own the page, you should use a page token anyway. but since you want to get comments, you probably know the post id - and the post id is tied to a page. if you want to get all posts too, use a page token with this endpoint: /me/posts

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. Let's me try your solution.